# Color div up to left of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following css...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .widediv{width:1366px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}
</style>
```

... that makes me create my page :

```
<body><div class="widedivv">
    <!-- Stuff -->
    <div style="background-color:#609ED2"> <!-- Stuff again --> </div>
</div></body>
```

But I use a 1600*900px screen, and I believe there's a clean way to do what I want :

> How to make the color of the div being applied up to the left of the screen/page ?

Because in this case, there will remain a white margin that has this width :

```
(ScreenWidth-1366)/2
```

Comment: Create something on codepen and share it here, please. It'll help people figure out what you're talking about because it isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry... : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJowyg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you like?

Html

```
<body><div class="widediv">
  <div style="background-color:blue; padding-left:350px">
    Stuff here
  </div>
</div>
&lt; I'd like the color of the div to get to there !
</body>
```

CSS

```
.widediv{background-color:blue;width:1366px;margin-right:auto}
```

Comment: Well, this is really a good idea, thanks for the tip ! I set this answer was right, but then, do you know a way of still centering the divs ? (cuz now, the whole page moved to the left...)

Answer (score 0):

cant you do something like this

```
<body>
 <div class="outer-widediv"> 
 <div class="widedivv">
    <!-- Stuff -->
    <div style="background-color:#609ED2"> <!-- Stuff again --> </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

and apply css as follows

```
.outer-widediv{
  background : color !important;
  position: relative;
}
.outer-widediv:after{
 content: ""; display: block; height: 100%;
}
.outer-widediv:before{
content: ""; display: block; height: 100%;
}
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wnq47yo/)

Comment: I don't really understand the goal of this... Here in your example, I'd like the red div's color to kinda "come out" of the blue div